# SparkViewEngine, RenderAction and Areas with ASP MVC 2 Beta?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine, asp.net-mvc-areas, renderaction

I just ran into trouble with the AreaDescriptionFilter of Spark using MVC 2 Beta.

The following line is from my Application.spark file. It results in the view engine looking in all possible locations of the view - except in the folders of the area "Shell".

`# Html.RenderAction("ShowMainMenu", "Navigation", new { area = "Shell" });`

Running the same action using `http://localhost/Shell/Navigation/ShowMainMenu` executes fine and recognizes the area's view directory as expected.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a known bug with Spark and some of the render methods. Did you try grabbing the latest version of Spark directly from its source repository?

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I looked into it and unfortunately it's not that simple.

Spark tries to find the area using:
context.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("area", out value)

The correct parameters appear in some the following dictionaries depending on the IsChildAction property of the context:

context.RouteData.DataTokens
context.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens
context.RequestContext.RouteData.Values

...the question is where should the framework put them by default (bugs aside) for Actions & ChildActions? 

I'll try quickfixing it with an "if" for now...

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a case mismatch?  Instead of area =

```
Html.RenderAction("ShowMainMenu", "Navigation", new { area = "Shell" });
```

you should have Area =

```
Html.RenderAction("ShowMainMenu", "Navigation", new { Area = "Shell" });
```

Comment: Actually it should be lowercase. All parameters like "controller", "action" and "id" are by convention lowercase.
The problem was some kind of conflict between one of the preview versions of MVC2 and SparkViewEngine - it works fine now!